# 100% width seems to not work on iOS

Tags: ios, css, width

I've seen a few posts about this but it does not seem to help with the issue I have used `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />` in the head but it does not solve the problem of the header and footer not spanning the width of the viewport. The main content area seems work though.

the site to reference is [brendanfenn.com](http://www.brendanfenn.com)

The css is as follows. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}


#header_container{
    background-image: url(http://www.brendanfenn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/headerBG1.jpg);
    width: 100%;    
}

#header {
    width:964px;
    height:150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    width:964px;
    background: url(images/border-bg.gif) repeat-y top left;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#content #left-col {
    width:615px;
    float:left;
    padding: 20px 11px 20px 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content #right-col {
    width:307px;    
    padding:3px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 1;
}


#footer {
    width:100%;
    background: #2a2006;    
    margin: 30px 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: No, % will not work on iOS webviews/safari. unfortunately, You will have to hardcode it and make sure you specify the pixel position.

Comment: Thanks, can you reccommend what to specify the width values if it needs to sapn the full width of the browser?

Comment: This was a serious issue for me as well in the past, apparently I had to detect the browser width dynamically and then inject it in the code. % never worked for me on iOS (even via objective-c webviews) either. You can make use of phonegap plugins to detect the width of the browser on iOS (Safari) device.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width and height values for your body element

```
body { width: 100%; min-height: 100% }
```

Another option that may help address the issue is using the @media type, which you can use to specify css values for when a device is in landscape mode.

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (min-width:400px) {
   body { //values here }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.4">
```

(From the linked file)
is your problem. This is setting your viewport to 800px wide (device-width * 1/0.4).

'width:100%' refers to 100% width of the viewport, i.e. 800px, so everything is working as it should.